# Escaping a clearsilver variable for use as a javascript parameter from an href

Tags: javascript, escaping, clearsilver

I'm using a clearsilver variable as a parameter to a javascript function, from an href. Like this:

```
<a href="javascript:foo('<?cs var: js_escape(bar) ?>');"><span>
```

This works great, until the cs variable contains quotes.

Anyone have experience with this? Is there some ordering of escaping that will work for this, or do I need to find a variable that doesn't have quotes in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did some more testing, this works:

```
<a href="javascript:foo('<?cs var: html_escape(js_escape(bar)) ?>');">
```